# Debian 11 fails to set IPv6 via Cloud-Init: "ens18/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory"

Tags: debian, cloud-init

When using Cloud-Init to set both a static IPv4 and IPv6 in the latest [Debian 11 (generic) cloud image](https://cdimage.debian.org/images/cloud/), `networking.service` throws the following error at boot:

```
Aug 16 14:28:29 debian ifup[540]: sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/ens18/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
```

Which seems about right, as there is no `ens18`:

```
$ ls /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/
all  default  eth0  lo
```

And, once the image is booted up, only the static IPv4 address is set:

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:b3:31:24:72:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s18
    altname ens18
    inet 1.2.3.4/26 brd 1.2.3.1 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::50b3:31ff:fe24:72f1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The `/etc/network/interfaces` config, however, is generated correctly by Cloud-Init:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
    dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 2a0d:1234:100::100
    dns-search vie.alwyzon.net

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 1.2.3.4/26
    gateway 1.2.3.1

# control-alias eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2a00:1234:1234:fee1::1/48
    gateway 2a00:1234:1234::1
```

The interface already was named `ens18` in Debian 10 (and also on other platforms: Ubuntu, CentOS, openSUSE, ...) and didn't make any issues there. (The choice of `ens18` is likely related to Proxmox; although I'm not exactly sure where/who made this choice.) However, this alias `eth0` pointing towards `ens18` seems new in Debian 11. In the Debian 10 images, `ens18` was just directly used and no `eth0` alias was shown anywhere.

**Any idea how I could make these new Debian 11 Cloud-Init images work with the `ens18` image?**

Comment: You could set the interface names to the old names by default, I'm not sure that this is done in the image. You need to edit /etc/default/grub and set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0". Then apply the changes in the bootloader - grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg .

Comment: Having a closer look at `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/cloud_inet6` (the failing script) it seems the failing check for `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/ens18/disable_ipv6` only occurs in the DHCP branch. Disabling DHCP (using statically set IPs anyhow) did the job for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a fix for this was now implemented by the Debian developers: [commit 1f67aed1](https://salsa.debian.org/cloud-team/debian-cloud-images/-/commit/1f67aed136b797f7a496717d2a08e384fe804f0c)

Running the [latest daily build](https://cloud.debian.org/images/cloud/bullseye/daily/) of the Debian 11 generic cloud images does solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ifupdown`, installing `ifupdown2` instead of `ifupdown` solved the problem here.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ifupdown2
```